# I have an old pyrex bowl with a detachable handle with a glass inset

Tags: equipment

Any idea to its age and since it has a flame imprint, can it be used on a gas stove?

A-C 833-B

Both pieces in near perfect condition.   Value?

Answer (score 2):

The flame indicates the 'flameware' line, which was made from 1936 to 1979.  [Corning states](https://www.cmog.org/article/pyrex):

> By 1936, just when the borosilicate glass patent used in bakeware was due to expire, Corning Glass Works released a new type of glass under the Pyrex brand name: FLAMEWARE, an aluminosilicate glass that could be used on the stove top. FLAMEWARE boasted many of the same virtues as Pyrex bakeware, such as cleanliness, cooking efficiency, and the ability to cook, serve and store in the same dish, and was marketed in the same advertisements as Pyrex. The FLAMEWARE line included saucepans, frying pans, teapots, and coffee percolators.

I found a [webpage saying it can be dated as the flame changed slightly over the years](http://www.ndga.net/articles/gmflameware.php), but they don't have examples to compare to; you might need to get a collector's guide.

As for value, you can look to see what those pieces have sold for on ebay or what the asking price is from 'replacement' type websites.  (although you won't get that much; they'll take their margin).  A recent collector's guide would likely be the most comprehensive place to look.  You might ask your library if they have one, or can get one through ILL (Inter-Library Loan)

Comment: +1. The "value" of the piece comes from nostalgia, so really checking prices for similar pieces on eBay is the way to go. Objectively it's not worth much (most likely). It's all in the eye of the beholder. That said, selling (or buying) on eBay is a risk since things can break during shipping. I'll look at china online, but I absolutely won't order it from anyone without a history and high ratings. So there are some practical aspects to consider beyond a reasonable price.

Comment: @kitukwfyer : realistically, something is worth whatever someone will give you cash for it, right this second.  So even if something sells for $200, once they're satisfied, the next person might only pay $30